# Error while creating snowpipe "COPY statement only supports simple SELECT from stage statements for import."

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a pipe (with auto ingest=true) and ingest data into Table1. I have a stage(@Stage) in json format,
Using Lateral Flatten, I need to ingest the json format, flatten it and insert into a snowflake table automatically using Pipe as new files come in.
When I do that, It gives and error
002098 (0A000): SQL compilation error:
COPY statement only supports simple SELECT from stage statements for import.

Sample code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PIPE PIPE1
AS
COPY INTO TABLE1 (
 Id,
 CustomerName,
 CustomerState,
 CustomerId,
 TransactionDate 
)
FROM (
 SELECT
    JSON.value:Id::string AS Id,
    JSON.value:Name::string AS Name,
    JSON.value:State::string AS State,
    JSON.value:CustomerId::int AS CustomerId,
  TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(JSON.value:Fields:Transactiondate::string, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TransactionDate
  FROM @Stage,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(PARSE_JSON($1)) JSON
 )
 FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'JSON');
```

Since it is autoingest, I cannot consume the json as a variant and then flatten it into destination table.
ideal way is for my flatten from snowflake stage and insert into snowflake table.
Pls advice.
I need to successfully create the pipe and not get any errors due to flatten function inside copy command

Goal is to sucessfully create the pipe

Comment: Hi - as the error message tells you, you can’t do this in the COPY INTO statement. You would need to do this in multiple steps e.g. use the pipe to load the data into a variant column and then process it in a second step using, for example streams and/or tasks